# Javascript that appends text when Facebook, Google+ or similar services are blocked by users

Tags: javascript, facebook, google-plus

If someone comes to my site with a browser plug like Ghostify, my Google+, Facebook etc. buttons go away. So I figured I should write some Javascript that checks if these are loaded based on selector contents or if the selector even exists, depending on the HTML of individual elements... And then append some text instead of the button

```
    $(document).ready(function () {

    /// Google+ : I check if it's div that was left has any content
    if ($(".g-plusone").html().length < 1 ) {
        $(".g-plusone").append('<p>Google+1 Blocked</p>');
    }

    /// Facebook I check if the widget selector even exists
    if (!$(".fb_iframe_widget").length) {
        $(".fb-like").append('<p>Facebook Like button blocked</p>');
    }   

    });
```

This seemed to work, and it still seems to work in every browser, except Firefox 11+.

I can't figure it out as it sometimes for example loads the appended Facebook text even if the div exists. And sometimes it loads the facebook button normally.

In other words the appending script triggers even if there's no blocking in firefox.

Any ideas?

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After fiddling with this for hours I off course remembered the RTFM method and went to the jquery documentation.

Before that I was trying out using .load() instead of .ready(). I figured if all the page was loaded before my script that there's no way it wouldn't work. But it didn't work.

Now after the docs I noticed I was using

```
  $(document).load(function ()
```

but what I really needed was

```
  $(window).load(function ()
```

DUH! Testing extensively it seems everything is working fine now. When the buttons are blocked by plugins my IF statements pick it up and display some text, otherwise they show fine.

Here's the current code that seems to be running fine, I need to tidy it up later, optimize if possible and stuff

```
    $(window).load(function () {

    var gplus = $("#node_movie_full_group_sharebuttons .g-plusone").html().length;
    var fejs = $("#node_movie_full_group_sharebuttons .fb_iframe_widget").length;
    var disq = !$("#dsq-content").length;

    if (gplus < 1) {
        $(".g-plusone").append('<p>Google+1 Blocked</p>');
        $(".field-name-sharebuttonsmovie .field-item").css("top", 0);
    }
    if (fejs < 1) {
        $(".fb-like").append('<p>Facebook Like button blocked</p>');
        $(".field-name-facemovie .field-item").css({ 'top': '0', 'left': '0' });
    }
    if (disq) {
        $("#disqus_thread").append('<p>Something is blocking the Disqus comments system</p>');
    }

});
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd guess that the plugins on Firefox remove the `.g-plusone` and `.fb-like` items.

Wrap your G+ and FB widgets in divs that are always there. Use ids and/or css classes that differ sufficiently from "g-plus" and "fb" so that over-zealous plugins don't remove your div as well.

Comment: Good point, I'll go test with that logic further. It seems that the Firefox behaviour is due to it's way of caching. At least I think so. On first load, and this is without blocking, the facebook button was there. After going to another page that uses the same script, instead of the facebook button I got the appended text. Confusing